# Simple way to restrict a function to only one instance

Tags: multithreading, mutex, instances

Every source just talks about classes. How do I ensure that only one instance of a function is running at a time in a multithreaded environment? The function will just be in a `while(true)` loop and has state conditions which the next set of data requires.

Comment: Possibly use a singleton?

Comment: Fixed formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0):

Functions are thread-agnostic by default. You can use a [critical section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_section) in the function body to restrict the execution to a single process.